# Can I modify android.view.View in Android

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I need to create a new method that can be used on several kinds of view objects. If I use inheritance I will have to create several new classes that extend Button/ImageView and etc. I was thinking that I could just add the new method in View.java but it does not seem to work. When I add the method it is not visible when I try to invoke it on any view object. Sorry if I'm asking a stupid question - I'm new to Android/Java and I need some advice.

Comment: inheritance is your only options as far as I can tell from your description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. Your code does not compile/build against the source that you downloaded. It builds against a JAR file. Even if you could add something to the source and compile against that, the code you added would not be present in the android JAR that exists on the user's device, so your app would crash.

Perhaps you should ask a new question describing what you want to be able to do and see if someone can suggest a way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was almost certain there is something major I'm missing...